# Unable to edit question although reputation (568) allows doing so

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits

For [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/46416/employee-agreement-wording-regarding-ownership-of-programs-developed-while-emplo) here, I am unable to edit the question as the edit button is disabled for some reason. My reputation, @ 568 allows me to edit questions. I was going to improve the format by converting the OP quotation into a block quote format so it stands out from the rest of the text in the question.

Comment: As @enderland has said, there was a pending suggested edit that prevented you from editing yourself.  We try to put tooltips on these kinds of items ([here's what it would have looked like](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ojcvs.png)), but these built-in browser tooltips are often overlooked and we're working on making them clearer (as in the new user profile).

Comment: @JarrodDixon yeah... I've used SE a long while now and never remember to look at the tooltips... oops :)

Answer (score 4):

Questions with suggested edits show up that way:

[image]

I approved the edit so you should also be able to edit now.